# replace if exact not containing in powershell

Tags: powershell, replace

I am attempting to replace lines in a text file. Once Valve 10 is replaced with Backup_Valve 1 how do I ensure the Valve 1 (in Backup_Valve 1) is not replace with Primary_Valve 1?

```
    cd C:\test
((Get-Content -path C:\test\*.txt -Raw) -replace ('Valve 10','Backup_Valve 1')) | Set-Content -Path C:\test\*.txt
((Get-Content -path C:\test\*.txt -Raw) -replace ('Valve 1','Primary_Valve 1')) | Set-Content -Path C:\test\*.txt
```

Comment: Surround the string to search with 'word boundary' characters `\b` like `-replace '\bValve 10\b', 'Backup_Valve 1'`. You should not use these brackets there

Comment: I'll try that thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As side from the word boundaries `\b`, did you know you can chain `-replace` operations?

Try

```
(Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\test' -Filter '*.txt' -File) | ForEach-Object {
    (Get-Content -Path $_.FullName -Raw) -replace '\bValve 10\b','Backup_Valve 1' -replace
                                                  '\bValve 1\b', 'Primary_Valve 1' |
     Set-Content -Path $_.FullName
}
```

This means you only use `Get-Content` once on each file, do multiple replacements on the content and write it back to file once.
The `-Raw` switch reads the file as one single string speeding up the code considerably.
The brackets around `Get-ChildItem` make sure it does not re-iterate files that were already processed earlier.

Comment: This worked great and looks much cleaner thank you!

Comment: @Ryan Thanks. Being new to the platform, you may not know this  but it's customary to mark the answer that solved your problem 'done' by clicking the large checkmark icon ✔️ on the left side of the answer.